# How to compress (resize?) >60k images on mac?

Tags: image, macos, compression

There are >60k images 10KB-1MB size and i need them all weighing <80KB, how do i go about this? Can't open so many images with preview. I guess there is a solution for this in terminal

Comment: Are they all in a single directory, or dotted around all over your disk? What format are they PNG/JPEG?

Comment: jpg in one directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First install **ImageMagick** and **GNU Parallel** with **homebrew**:

```
brew install imagemagick
brew install parallel
```

Then go to the directory where the images are and create an output directory:

```
cd where/the/images/are
mkdir output
```

Now run **ImageMagick** from **GNU Parallel**

```
find . -name "*.jpg" -print0 | parallel -0 magick {} -define jpeg:extent=80kb output/{}
```